# VLC Wait for Frame

Tags: vlc-media-player, framerate, framebuffer

I have a HD video that I would like to play without it being choppy with a grey frame (eg. when it is not being decoded fast enough)

I could manually turn the playback speed down until it works, but I would like a better alternative (eg. perhaps through a setting)

So my question is, "How do I have VLC wait for the current frame to finish loading, before the next one?"

I do not care if it takes a longer time and I don't care if the audio will be out of sync

Comment: I haven't had this issue, so I don't know the answer, but I did a search on vlc performance tuning and came up with a ton of results. You may want to limit the search to the last year or so (google option) to skip really old results.

Comment: It is lagging / having grey choppy frames because I will be purposely limiting the maximum CPU usage for VLC on a somewhat low-end laptop (older than 5 years). Thus the results on Google aren't much use (they assume it is lagging only a bit or that it is just the network that is slow)